# How come my state isn't being filled with response?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

console.log(data) gives me an object with the correct data but, I set rates to that data but when console logging rates I get an empty object {}. Thanks in advance.

```
const [rates, setRates] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    search();
  }, []);

  const search = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get('https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest');
    const data = response.data.rates;
    console.log(data);
    setRates(data);
    console.log(rates);
  };
```

Comment: Don't use `rates` inside `search`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately) TL;DR react state is const, asynchronous in nature, and updates *between* render cycles.

Comment: Yeah, what Drew said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone said in the comment, state updates will be reflected in the next render. Also, there are some problems with your code I'll address.

```
  const [rates, setRates] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
      // move this in here unless you plan to call it elsewhere
      const search = async () => {
          const response = await axios.get('https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest');
          const data = response.data.rates;
          setRates(data);
       };
    search();

  }, [/* no dependencies means it runs once */]);
```

If you *do* plan on calling `search` elsewhere, wrap it in a `useCallback` hook so you can set it as a dependency of your `useEffect` (you'll get a lint warning without). `useCallback` with an empty dependency array will always return the same function reference, so your `useEffect` will only ever run the one time like it does now.

If you leave `search` as a normal function in the component, the reference changes *each render*, so your effect would run every render if you included it as a dependency.

```
 const [rates, setRates] = useState({});  
 const searchCallback = useCallback(async () => {
      const response = await axios.get('https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest');
      const data = response.data.rates;
      setRates(data);
  }, [])

 useEffect(() => {
      // move this in here unless you plan to call it elsewhere
      
    search();

 }, [searchCallback]);
```